# Pandas Multiindex and Groupby returns odd behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-groupby

I am working with Pandas MultiIndex Dataframes for a few weeks now and I have the feeling that I do not really get the intuition behind the GroupBy object, especially the choosing of groups.

Let's take this code for example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

df.groupby(level=0).first()
```

The output of the last line is this:

```
            0         1         2         3
bar  1.612350 -0.019424 -0.088925 -0.188864
baz  2.752485 -1.011006  0.249788  1.106547
foo  1.313016  0.716512  0.550851 -1.532394
qux  1.505173  0.758075  1.360808  1.261204
```

However, this behavior does not make much sense in my opinion, because it gives me the first group as if I would have grouped by the second level. What I expect from the code above is this:

```
            0         1         2         3
one  1.612350 -0.019424 -0.088925 -0.188864
two  0.434829  1.698503 -0.213425  0.329733
```

Until now, I achieved what I wanted by doing this:

```
list(df.groupby(level=0))[0][1]
```

But, this does not look like its meant to be done this way.

Somehow, it seems that I have wrong expectations of the GroupBy object. Maybe someone can help me solve my confusion :).

**Additional Info:**
I am not looking for a specific solution, how to get the "first group" since I already got it by creating a list out of the object. My question is rather regarding the understanding of the GroupBy object and why it chooses the first (or any other group) the way it does.

Comment: I think your misunderstanding is related to what the `first` method does: it doesn't select the first group, it selects the first item in each group.

Comment: @user2285236 that is exactly the answer I was looking for :). 
However, I can't see, why there is a method for getting the first (or nth) member of each group, but not a method for the nth group.

Comment: Yeah pandas only allows selecting group by keys (as in `df.groupby(level=0).get_group('foo')`) This is probably because by default it doesn't preserve the original ordering and sorts them by key. Your keys are already ordered so you don't see the problem at `list(df.groupby(level=0))[0][1]
` but if your first group was `qux`, you would get `bar` again. `nth` group in this case might be ambiguous, probably that's why they only allow accessing groups by keys.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now everything makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Is you looking for multiple index slice ?

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['bar',:],:]
Out[319]: 
                0        1         2         3
bar one  0.807706  0.07296  0.638787  0.329646
    two -0.497104 -0.75407 -0.943406  0.484752
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first column is level_0, but you want to group by level_1. If you reset the index both columns will be assigned a column header which you can group by

add this code:

```
df=df.reset_index()

df=df.groupby(['level_1']).first()
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `MultiIndex` levels names and then use [`pd.DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df.index.names = ['first', 'second']
res = df.query('first == "bar"')

print(res)

                     0         1         2         3
first second                                        
bar   one     0.555863 -0.080074 -1.726498 -0.874648
      two     1.099309  0.047887  0.294042  0.222972
```

Alternatively, using [`pd.Index.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html):

```
res = df[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'bar']
```

Comment: No name can access by ilevel_0 :-)

Comment: Oh nice tip! But I like names :)

Answer (score 0):

Since my question was answered by @user2285236 in the comments, I try to summary it.

The method `first()` does not select the first group, but the first entry of every group. The reason why there is no built-in implementation something like `list(df.groupby(level=0))[0][1]` is that `groupby()` method sorts the entries.

For example, lets arrange the example above and make the 'first' group  'qux?. Which would look like this:

```
arrays = [['qux', 'qux', 'bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=index)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)
```

the call of `list(df.groupby(level=0))[0][1]` returns:

```
                0         1         2         3
bar one -0.335708 -0.315253 -0.087970  0.754242
    two -1.608651  1.005786  1.800341 -1.059510
```

rather than the 'first' group, which I expect to be:

```
                0         1         2         3
qux one -0.374186  0.812865  0.578298 -0.901881
    two -0.137799  0.278797 -1.171522  0.319980
```

However, every group can be called with the built-in method `get_group()`. Hence, in this case, I could get the 'first' group by calling: `df.groupby(level=0).get_group('qux')`